# Concourse CI - S3 trigger not firing. How often does it check?

Tags: concourse

I've got a Concourse job that uses the appearance of a file in an Amazon S3 bucket as a trigger to a suite of tests. Using this resource --> https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource . Problem is, the job is not firing when the file appears. When I trigger the job manually, it does see the file and start the test suite.

Yaml config looks like this:

```
- name: s3-trigger-file
  type: s3
  source:
    bucket: my-bucket-name
    regexp: qabot_request_(.*).json
    access_key_id: {{s3-access-key-id}}
    secret_access_key: {{s3-secret-access-key}}

jobs:
  - name: my-job
    public: true
    plan:
    - get: s3-trigger-file
      trigger: true
```

When I click on the trigger itself in the Concourse UI, I see what looks like a running monitor:

[image: seems to be waiting ok]
As I said, the job isn't firing when the file appears, but a manual trigger does verify the S3 input is found.

How can I debug why the automatic trigger isn't firing? Also, how much latency is expected for the s3 resource to detect a new file has appeared?

Concourse 3.4. Thanks ~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capturing group in your regexp must refer to a semver compliant version.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource#file-names):

> The version extracted from this pattern is used to version the resource. Semantic versions, or just numbers, are supported. Accordingly, full regular expressions are supported, to specify the capture groups.

Your capturing group is currently making the captured "version" `quote2`. You should probably delete the pipeline and regenerate it with a modified regex (e.g. `qabot_request_quote(\d+).json`)

Comment: any particuar reason to delete + recreate, as opposed to just update?

Comment: The "version" saved in your database will still be "quote2" which it cannot compare to the updated version "2".

Deleting the pipeline will delete the resource versions and start again.